# `gcloud beta dataflow` not listing job details

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, gcloud

I'm using the [Dataflow command line tool](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dataflow-command-line-intf) to understand my Dataflow jobs.

```
gcloud dataflow jobs list
```

works without problems and gives me a long list of jobs. Once I however want to investigate a certain job using

```
gcloud beta dataflow jobs describe $JOBID
```

I always get:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.dataflow.jobs.describe) NOT_FOUND: Requested entity was not found.
```

I've tried multiple different job ids, and also tried `gcloud beta dataflow metrics list $JOBID` but to no avail.

*What am I doing wrong?*

Comment: The error message means that something is wrong with $JOBID. Try using the actual job id on the command line.

Comment: Yes, I did use the actual job id, I did this just for illustration purposes.

Comment: One item that I noticed. You are using `beta` commands. I am using the normal commands without `beta`. Also try `gcloud components update`

Comment: Tried, also doesn't work. I also tried multiple quoting strategies and putting "<"/">" around the job id, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with explicit --region parameter. You can see the region in list command. I had same issues and specifying the region helped. Make also sure you use job id, not job name. You do not need to quote the jobid if it does not include special characters.

Comment: Adding `--region` helped.